# Pixelate Image via brick Texture

Tags: shaders

Can I use a procedural texture as color input for a brick Texture and than "round" the value per cell?
Kinda like pixelation -> every brick is a pixel.

Comment: I don't think you can, without doing as much work as it would take to make your own bricks. But that's not too much. Is there any particular reason you want to use the built-in _Bricks_?

Comment: No not really, I just want to have a node that takes a texture input and outputs a pixelated version. Kinda like manipulating the vector going into the texture with the vector math snap node, but instead achieve this effect after the texture.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own, simplified Brick group node for that.

The main idea is to take a vector as input, and return the "brixelized" vector that should be sampled for that location.

To simply pixelate, we can snap the X and Y values to a certain increment. Then, to offset them in one direction, add-before-snap and subtract-after-snap by the value you want to offset. The latter depends on the X tile index for bricks:

[image: brixelize node setup]

Then, you can use your brixelize group. Here's my brixelized Suzanne:

[image: monke]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as you can read in the comments on my question, I was already familiar with this solution. I was looking for a different solution.